# The requested URL /contacts was not found on this server - trying to set up cakePHP on ubuntu and getting this error

Tags: php, ubuntu, mod-rewrite, cakephp

My project works fine on Openserver in Windows. But now I am trying to transfer it to Ubuntu. 
So the home page is available (but all external scrips, css, js and images returns 404 error). Also, every internal page is not available (The requested URL /blablabla was not found on this server).
What am I doing wrong? 
Mod_rewrite is enabled, apache logs have no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out.
Just need replace

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In `apache.conf`